# AdControl not show ads

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp, ads

in my application I have the following code:

```
 <UI:AdControl x:Name="ban2" Grid.Row="1" ApplicationId="xx"
                  AdUnitId="xx"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Height="80"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="480"></UI:AdControl>
```

When using the test aplicationid and adunitId working properly, but when I go to replace with aplicationid and adunitId of my application created in the dev center no longer displays advertising.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't publish your app in the store, the Application Id and Adunit Id will do not work.

So I would like to suggest you use test Application Id and AdUnit Id to test when you create your project. if you want to package your project and submit in the store, you just need to replace test value with real value(Apply for in the dashboard).

Normally, if your app is published and available in the store, it takes 1-2 days after that for ads from real units to start serving and ads will show.

Comment: the application is published in the storie.

Comment: If your app has been published in the store, I would like to suggest to wait 1-2 days to check if the ads are showing. Thank you!

Comment: Still does not appear.

Comment: I have reported this issue to Microsoft related team, I will update if I get any reply.

Comment: @Andrea485,Do you have resolved your issue? Microsoft may have fixed this issue yesterday, if you have any problem or not, please let me know when you feel free.Thank you.

Comment: @Cherry Bu and @ Andrea485. I have the same problem, Test Ads are working in my UWP app, but by putting Live IDs , now it doesn't work, even 2 weeks spent, but didn't get any single impression from Ads. The Supported sizes are accurate and App ID and Ad Unit IDs are put accurate, but still no Ads. What to do please?