# UWP AdControl not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, ads, windows-dev-center

Ad control working fine when i use test Id, test ads are displayed, but control empty when i try to set values from my deshboard for a real ad. Ad mediator is enabled.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <advertisment:AdControl ApplicationId="App_Id_Of_Ad_from_Dashboard"
                                AdUnitId="11689013"
                                Width="480"
                                Height="80"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is my dashboard keys for a unit
[image]

Comment: This question is already answered in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259772/adcontrol-not-show-ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you published your app? The real ad unit need you to publish your app successfully and it will begin to work after around 24 hours.

Besides, please note that you'd better select a proper [**banner size**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads#windows-10-uwp-and-windows-81) so that your ad can be displayed well. If the real unit id still doesn't work, please feel free to share your Ad unit so that I can forward it to related team. Or you can create a free [**support ticket**](http://aka.ms/storesupport) to report your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, Test Ads are working in my UWP app, but by putting Live IDs , now it doesn't work, even 2 weeks spent, but didn't get any single impression from Ads. The Supported sizes are accurate and App ID and Ad Unit IDs are put accurate, but still no Ads. What to do please?

Comment: the support ticket is not working ... you said if we share the ad units, you will forward it to the related team, so I will share after your reply.